# How to access nested divs using Jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

This is the html page:

```
<div class="doc_details">
  <fieldset style="border: 0pt">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <b>Speciality</b>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">ABCD</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <b>City</b>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">Ranchi</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <b>Residence Address</b>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">Ranchi</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <b>Business Address</b>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">Ranchi</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

I would like to access only the values of the Speciality, city and address columns into a variable as follows:

```
Elements rows = doc.select("div.doc_details div.row div.row ");
Element row_div = rows.select("div.row").get(0);
doctor.speciality = row_div.select("div:eq(0)").text();
```

But even if I change the `get(0)` to `get(1)`, I'm not able to get only the values in the variable.

Answer (score 3):

You can probably do this with a css-selector :

```
doc.select("div.row > div.col-sm-6:nth-child(2)")
```

which returns this :

```
0 = {Element@754} "<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">\n  ABCD \n</div>"
1 = {Element@756} "<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">\n  Ranchi \n</div>"
2 = {Element@758} "<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">\n  Ranchi \n</div>"
3 = {Element@760} "<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">\n  Ranchi \n</div>"
```

It's then really up to you, you can for example map the list to the text of each div :

```
    divs.stream().map(new Function<Element, String>() {
        @Override
        public String apply(Element element) {
            return element.text();
        }
    }).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

or more simple :

```
String speciality = divs.get(0).text();
String city = divs.get(1).text();
String adress = divs.get(2).text();
```

Comment: How fancy! :) Very nice.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Elements rows = doc.select("div.doc_details div.row div.row ");
Element row_div = rows.select("div.col-sm-6").get(1);
doctor.speciality = row_div.text();
```

tell me if it works!

Comment: This works : doctor.speciality = rows.select("div.col-sm-6").get(1).text(); doctor.city = rows.select("div.col-sm-6").get(3).text();
   doctor.residence_address = rows.select("div.col-sm-6").get(5).text(); But this does not work: Element ba = rows.select("div.col-sm-6").get(7);
   if(ba!=null) doctor.business_address = ba.text();

Answer (score 1):

Here is how  I would do it:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements rows = doc.select("div.doc_details div.row div.row ");
for (Element row : rows){
    Elements innerDivs = row.select("div");
    String header = innerDivs.get(1).text();
    String content = innerDivs.get(2).text();
    System.out.println("header = "+header+ " -> "+content);
}
```

I think you were mistaken in the css selector!

Edit: (thanks to the OP the indexes are correct now)