# How to extract text from inter DIV with Jsoup?

Tags: android, android-studio, web-scraping, jsoup

I am trying to extract a text from a div class inside of a main div class. One example of a code snippet i am trying to use is:

Eg.

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="01"></div> 
  <div class="02"></div>
  <div class="03">
     <span class=""></span>
     <div class="content"> **TEXT TO EXTRACT** </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

My code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connet(url).get();
Elements title01 = doc.select("div.main > div > div > div");

txt01 = title01.text();
```

This code don't work. What is wrong?

Comment: maybe this can help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/32027496/4229514

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is very simple:

```
Elements elements = doc.select("div.main div.content");
```

If the content div doesn't have to be within a main div you can do this instead:

```
Elements elements = doc.select("div.content");
```

### **Why your code doesn't work**

1. `div.main` get every `div` with class `main`
   **CurrentCollection = {main}**

```html
<div class="main"> 
 ......
</div>
```

2. `> div` searches `div.main` for `div` children
   **CurrentCollection = {01, 02, 03}**

```html
    <div class="01"></div> 
    <div class="02"></div>
    <div class="03">.....</div>
```

3. `> div` seaches every element in `CurrentCollection` for `div` children
      **CurrentCollection = {content}**

```html
        <div class="content"> **TEXT TO EXTRACT** </div>
```

4. `> div` searches every element in `CurrentCollection` for `div` children
   **CurrentCollection = {}**

Comment: class=content is only an E.g ... if this class is CLASS=""    ? its my case

Comment: the right way for me is "div.main > div + div + div" ... but, thx friend